# MySql Create Function Solutions Immediately

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
create function COMP_STMT(activeSTMT varchar(200),activeSQL varchar(200)) RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        PREPARE activeSTMT from activeSQL;
        EXECUTE activeSTMT;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE activeSTMT;
        return 1;
    END;
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@activeSTMT from @activeSQL' at line 3
```

How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use string literal or a user variable that contains the text of the statement to work with PREPARE/EXECUTE statement in Mysql.

```
BEGIN
 set @actSQL= activeSQL;
 PREPARE stmt FROM @actSQL;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```